# How can I make this simple Python program solve an equation for given inputs from a GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have this code I made and I am trying to get python to solve an equation with variables assigned values from a GUI, then display the answer. You should only need to give two of the variables values and the rest should solve. I am still pretty new to python. Its for a game, heres what I got:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()

        self.d = 0
        self.size = 0
        self.mil = 0
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.L1 = Label(self)
        self.L2 = Label(self)
        self.L3 = Label(self)

        self.L1.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
        self.L2.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        self.L3.grid(column = 1, row = 3)

        self.L1["text"] = "Distance from Target " + str(self.d) + "m" 
        self.L2["text"] = "Size of Target " + str(self.size) + "mils"
        self.L3["text"] = "Mil Dot adj " + str(self.mil)


        self.entryd = Entry(self, bd=5)
        self.entryd.grid(column = 2, row = 1, padx = 10)
        self.entrysize = Entry(self, bd=5)
        self.entrysize.grid(column = 2, row = 2)
        self.entrymil = Entry(self, bd=5)
        self.entrymil.grid(column = 2, row = 3)

        self.button1 = Button(self)
        self.button1["text"] = "Calculate Kill Shot"
        self.button1["command"] = self.calc
        self.button1.grid(column = 2, row = 4)



    def calc(self):
        self.d = self.entryd.get()
        self.size = self.entrysize.get()
        self.mil = self.entrymil.get()

        self.L1["text"] = "Distance from Target " + str(self.d) + "m" 
        self.L2["text"] = "Size of Target " + str(self.size) + "mils"
        self.L3["text"] = "Mil Dot adj " + str(self.mil)

        #self.d = self.size * 1000 / self.mil
    #above is the equation i tried using. 


root = Tk()
root.title("heeey")
root.geometry("400x400")
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Ive seen some people use sympy and i tried but couldn't get it. Any info would really help thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only problem is accurately being described by the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

That's telling you that you're trying to divide a string by a string. All you need to do is convert your strings to numbers before doing the calculation:

```
self.d = int(self.size) * 1000 / int(self.mil)
```